# How to lock input[type=file]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to lock my input files from editing by user while I'm submitting my files in a chain (through wrappers and callbacks).

Although it was easy to lock my form just by adding readonly attributes to the input elements:

```
$('form input').attr('readonly','readonly');
```

It just doesn't work on input files.

The `disabled` attribute kinda works, but it wouldn't submit the file then...

So, any ideas how to lock it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `preventDefault()` method of the `event` object, try the following:

```
$('input[type=file]').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LvXJJ/

Comment: Strangely but it works :-) I thought input files wouldn't allow much scripting but this isn't the case it seems

Answer (score -2):

```
or you can try this:
$('input[type=file]').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```